# PHP Get variable in other file than php (eg. MP4)

Tags: php, variables, post, get, stream

So i was browsing through the web and found a video, upon inspecting the video source i found out that it had a get variable in the url, it looked like this:

```
http://www.blablabla.com/stream/2017/09/2a5ef169.mp4?expires=1302948611&token=1290239327
```

this part got my interest:

```
2a5ef169.mp4?expires=1302948611&token=1290239327
```

Its a MP4 file but accepts get variables. if those variables do not match a certain function i am not able to view the video so i think its linked to a php file.

I do know how GET and POST works in PHP but how do i apply this to a MP4 file or any other file.

Comment: its not a mp4 file, its a php file, that serves a mp4

Comment: They could be using any language on the server.

Comment: The server might be rewriting the URL to point to a script in some language that processes URL parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Just because the extension ends in mp4, it doesn't mean "there is an mp4 file somewhere".
consider .htaccess can change extensions and using mod_rewrite or similar, people can redirect a given "clean" url to any php program.

So there *may* be a php interpreter behind the mp4 requests, and apache may have a modified httpd.conf or .htaccess file which routes /(.*).mp4 requests into a serve_video.php program (or whatever the name is).

This means in general, extensions don't mean anything.

by using HTTP header()s, the server might be responding dynamically (example: https://gist.github.com/ranacseruet/9826293) to each request (potentially in order to log the video's view count or something similar, like checking the HTTP REFERER in order to avoid hotlinking)

Hope that helps!